# Line plot appears empty

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data arranged in two columns, and I am trying to plot it using ggplot:

```
year_month    avg
   <chr>       <dbl>
 1 2015-07     9470.
 2 2015-08    12113.
 3 2015-09    13532.
 4 2015-10    11129.
 5 2015-11    12550.
 6 2015-12    10830.
 7 2016-01    12835.
 8 2016-02    11907.
 9 2016-03    12799.
10 2016-04    12437.
11 2016-05    11860.
12 2016-06    11521.

ggplot(data=time_series_yr,aes(x=year_month))+
  geom_line(aes(y=avg))
```

[image: empty_plot]

But when I use the geom_point() It doesn´t appear empty.

```
ggplot(data=time_series_yr,aes(x=year_month))+
  geom_point(aes(y=avg))
```

[image]

How can I get the line plot as well.

I try to use `geom_line()` to get a line plot, but it retrieved an empty plot.

Comment: Try `df %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(year_month, avg, group=1))`. Group defines the connected cases.

Comment: ^ and the reason the lines aren't connecting by default is that your `year_month` is character data, which is interpreted by ggplot as categories, as if one point relates to "chicken" and another to "hippo," which by default are assumed to be separate things and not part of the same group that should be connected. `group = 1` (or `group = "anything here")` overrides that. You could also convert your `year_month` (e.g. with `lubridate::ym`) into dates, which would place them on a timeline and then making the group override unnecessary.